# Disjunctive normal form and shannon normal form

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Consider the formula (( true | (a <-> b)) & ((c | b) ^ a ^ b)). transform the formula into disjunctive normal form for the variable ordering a ≤ b ≤ c ≤ d. Also transform to Shannon normal form with arbitrary ordering.

I am new to this sort of questions. I don't know how to begin to solve the question.

Answer (score 1):

To transform the formula to [DNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form), go through the following steps:

1. Write a truth table which shows the function value for all $2^n$ possible input combinations
2. Take the truth table rows for which the function value is $false$
3. Invert the inputs in each of the rows from step 2.
4. The result is a set of disjunctions which together constitute a [DNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form)

To get the [Shannon normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram) (commonly called *if-then-else Normal Form INF*), apply the [Shannon expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_expansion_theorem) recursively.
In your case, apply it first for variable $a$, then $b$ and so forth.

The [Shannon expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_expansion_theorem) of a function $f(a, b, c)$ is written as:

$$f(a, b, c) = a \land f(a=1, b, c) \lor \bar{a} \land f(a=0, b, c)$$

Comment: Can we also try the rules? like eliminating the arrows first and so on ?

Comment: You could try to save some work by prior simplification, but a truth table for three variables is not that long anyhow.